# Send message to C++/Qt application from outside?

Tags: java, c++, qt, ipc, dbus

I have a C++/Qt application. I want to talk to it using Java.
I know I can create TCP server/client. What other options do I have?

The problem is that I created TCP server inside the application and it does not work. But works fine when run in standalone mode. So looking for alternatives ways of communication between C++ and Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a C++/Qt application. I want to talk to it using Java. I know I
>   can create TCP server/client. What other options do I have?

Basically, what you are looking for is IPC that is supported by both languages properly. You can find several solutions out there:

- [Java and C++ socket communication.](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/java-and-c-socket-communication/222900697). Obviously, QtNetwork and the socket classes in there could be your friend for this on the Qt side.
- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t279534-communication-between-a-c-and-java-program.html
- [Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). You would be able to call C/C++ methods from Java and vice versa, although this would be probably one of the slowest solutions.
- [Shared Memory (SHM)](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html) (Here, [QSharedMemory](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qsharedmemory.html) could aid you on the Qt side).
- [Google Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview?csw=1)
- Dbus (Here, [QtDbus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdbus-index.html) could aid you on the Qt side). This is not necessarily cross-platform a solution, however.

I would personally suggest to use raw socket based low-level solution with the Qt API. This is the most reliable in my opinion, and well-proven technology behind. There is [Qt Jambi](http://qt-jambi.org/) with Qt style API for the java side, and then of course in C++, you will get the [QtNetwork API](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qtnetwork-index.html). This would at least provide you some consistency throughout the projects.